# Legendre transform approximation

Tags: analysis, approximation, legendre-transformation

Is there any good rational approximation of the Legendre transform of the function $$f(x)=\log\left(\frac{e^x-1}{x}\right)$$
I tried to approximate the derivate of $f$, using Taylor, however, the function I got was not a good approximation, since it wasn't always positive and having infite limits at $0$ and at $1$.

Comment: Good on which interval ? Near 0 ?

Comment: On the interval (0,1).

Comment: No for "rational" because the singularity at both endpoints is logarithmic, but $-\log(x(1-x))-1-4x(1-x)(\log(4)-1)$ seems decent enough to me.

Comment: @fedja Nice! How did you come up with this? Is there a general method?

Comment: I just took the asymptotic at the endpoints and adjusted it a bit by the last term to have exact value ($0$) in the middle. If you need more precision, that can be achieved too, but it will require more work :-)

Comment: don't know if going to help, but I found [this approximation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+x+%2B+ln%282%29*ProductLog%280%2C+-%28e%5E%28-x%2Fln%282%29%29*x%29%2Fln%282%29%29-ln%28x%29%2C+ln%28%28e%5Ex-1%29%2Fx%29&lang=es) that suits for values far away from zero